# SSRS - Return to the line with column group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I've got a problem about SSRS design.

I need to make a report to display a list of item size.

I need to have 1 line per item with all the size of this item (and the quantity) on the same line

[SSRS Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLFqQ.png)
The "Row group" have a grouping on the "Item No" field.

[Actual result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsIOu.png)

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtgmH.png)

How can you put line 2 back to the beginning?

Thanks everyone for your help !

Data :

| Item No | Size | Qty |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1896-S | T32 | 4 |
| 1896-S | T34 | 3 |
| 1906-S | T32 | 2 |
| 1906-S | T34 | 4 |
| 1906-S | T36 | 5 |

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It's generally a good idea to post pictures inside the body of the question rather than link to them. People may be reluctant to click on outside links, and future link rot means at some point critical context will be missing from the question so the answer(s) may not help people who have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily with a matrix control.

Drop a Matrix control onto your report and then drag `Item_No` to the 'Rows' placeholder, `Size` to the 'Columns' placeholder and `Qty` to the 'Data' placeholder.

this will will give you a basic matrix, the design looks like this...

[image]

And it will look like this when rendered..

[image]

This is not quite what you wanted but we can soon change that.

All you need to do is change the expression in the 'Data' cell from `[Sum(qty)]` to something like this ...

```
=FIRST(Fields!Size.Value) & " " & Sum(Fields!Qty.Value)
```

Now when we render we get this...

[image]

If you want to put line breaks in etc then you can just edit the expression to suit. Alternatively you can use placeholders in the cell to have even more control of the layout and formatting.